# Modular Division For non co-prime numbers

Tags: modular-arithmetic

How can I calculate $(x*k)/i$ **(mod $m$)** where i and m are relatively **not co-prime** ?

We know that, if $\gcd(i,m)\neq1$ , then there doesn't exist a modular multiplicative inverse of **$i$** **mod $m$**. Then how can it be solved?

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 2):

As imu96 remarked, there is no solution in the general case.

However, if $(x*k)/\gcd(i,m)$ is an integer, you could calculate it using:
$$
(x*k)/i \equiv (x*k)\Big/\left(\gcd(i,m)*\frac{i}{\gcd(i,m)}\right)\pmod m
\\\equiv (x*k/\gcd(i,m))*\left(\frac{i}{\gcd(i,m)}\right)^{-1}  \pmod m
$$

Note that $\frac{i}{gcd(i,m)}$ and $m$ are co-prime.

Answer (score 1):

If $i$ and $m$ are not coprime, then $i$ does not have a multiplicative inverse and so, there is no solution to the equation.

If you think about it, it makes sense for there to be no solution because you are essentially trying to multiply by a number that doesn't exist.